# Foreground service being stopped by Android does not restart later

Tags: android, android-service, thread-sleep, foreground-service

I have a Foreground Service for my app, which must run the whole time and never stops. While I was testing it few times, it seems after 3-4 days Android decides it just to stop it, and never restart it again, and in my Activity I have a check for the service if its running, and if it isnt to start it.
Even though, the service is not starting, and I can't debug it, because this is not happening immidiatelly.
So this is my check, is there something wrong in it?

```
if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)) {
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

I call this check in onResume() of the Activity, and I can't just run it everytime when the activity starts, because I have a constantly running Thread in the service, which will get more than one instance if started several times...

So here is what I want:
Either have more reliable way to check for the service if its running
or
Just start the service every time the activity starts, to prevent problems, and the thread inside of it must always have just 1 instance (I have already declared is as static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your service `Bindable` and bind your `Activity` to the service when the `Activity` starts/resumes. This way you will be sure the service is running. But I think you have a problem with your service. My I ask you to post more information about the service? It is not normal the OS to kill a foreground service with no traces.

Comment: what you need to know?

Comment: What does ```ForegroundService.buildForeground(this, allowedCigarette)``` do?

Comment: It makes this => http://pastebin.com/xnCqHXVF

makes the Foreground notification for the service (up in the taskbar)

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. Everything seems OK with your service... You can try the approach with binding. This way you will be sure the service is running.